# How to set localStorage variables properly

Tags: javascript, local-storage

What is the proper way to set a variable in localStorage?

`localStorage.hello = 'world'`

or

`localStorage.setItem('hello','world')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The method used is very unlikely to matter. [The standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webstorage.html#dom-storage-setitem-dev) lists that the following methods are equivalent:

> ```
> storage.setItem (key, value)
> storage[key] = value
> ```
>
> Sets the value of the pair identified by key to value, creating a new key/value pair if none existed for key previously.

Very unusual situations in which `setItem` and `getItem` would be preferred over dot notation assignment or retrieval would be when properties on the prototype might be referenced - such as with `.length` and `.__proto__`. (But dynamic storage keys are a pretty bad idea - better to organize them into their own array or object in a single storage key instead. If the keys aren't dynamic, such collisions shouldn't occur in sane code, unless someone forgot that `length` is reserved)

For an example of a problematic use of `length` with dot notation:

```
localStorage.length = '123'
console.log(localStorage.length)
```

will not give you `123`, but the number of keys in storage. (The assignment silently fails.) On the other hand, using `setItem` and `getItem` with `length` (or any other arbitrary string) will work.

`getItem` and `setItem` are also more compatible with type-checking systems like TypeScript and Flow than dot notation.

Personally, when I'm not using TypeScript, and when the storage key is static, I use dot notation because it's more concise and doesn't cause any problems.